# How to fix MissingPermissions error not working | discord.py

Tags: error-handling, discord.py

I've set up a `*ban` command and it uses the `@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)` decorator. However, my error-handler doesn't seem to pick up on `if isinstance (error, MissingPermissions):`.

```py
@client.command(name="ban", pass_ctx=True)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member=None, *, reason: str=None):
    # command is here but irrelevant i think

@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, BadArgument): # members != @user
        await ctx.send("Please specify a **valid** user!")
    elif isinstance(error, MissingPermissions): # can't ban
        await ctx.send("You need the **ban members** permission")
    else:
        raise error
```

It doesn't get caught by the error handler, but my terminal [vscode] does produce this: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden:
403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` I assumed this was what `MissingPermissions` does? Anyway, I'm stumped as to why this doesn't work, so help is appreciated :)

Also note that this same code works on my [kick](https://pastebin.com/PtiY4aQD) command somehow?

Comment: The error mentions the manage Messages permission, not the Ban Members permission.  Are you sure you're using the right command?  Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: Apologies. Re-ran the ban command with insufficient permission and got the correct error message now: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden:
403 FORBIDDEN (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions` - no mention of messages OR ban.

Comment: So is this solved or.. what is exactly the current problem?

Comment: It looks like the bot itself doesn't have permission to ban users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I tried to ban someone with administrator (not gunna work).

However, I will probably add errors for if the bot can't ban the person:

```py
try:
    await member.ban() # member: discord.Member
except discord.Forbidden: # the error being raised
    await ctx.send(f"I don't have permission to ban **{member}**")
```

This makes sure the bot can actually ban the user being mentioned (tested & working)